# Matplotlib scalarformatter not converting y-ticks to standard form

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to use ScalarFormatter to convert my y-axis ticks into standard form, but after much experimenting I'm experiencing no success and I can't figure out why. MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import scipy.constants as const

k = 1/(4*np.pi*const.epsilon_0)
def force_e(q_1,q_2,x):
    return k*q_1*q_2/x**2

d = 10
delta = 0.1*d
x = np.linspace(0+delta,d-delta,1000)
q1 = 2e-6
q2 = -2e-6
q = 1e-9
F = force_e(q1,q,x) - force_e(q2,q,d-x)

fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,6))

ax1.plot(x, F)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))

ax1.set_xlabel("Separation $r$ (m)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Force $F$ (N)")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It produces a figure as so:

[image]

where as I would like it to display 1.75x10^5 etc.

Comment: Remove the line that sets the formatter and replace it with `ax1.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(-2,2), useMathText=True)`.